# Why `margin: 1 auto;` doesn't work?

Tags: css

Why `margin: 0 auto;` works but `margin: 1 auto;` doesn't? Is there some hackish way to simply fix this?

```css
      .container {
       width: 220px;
       /* margin: 0 auto; */ /* <-- works.*/
       margin: 1 auto; /*<-- error. HOW TO FIX??? */
       padding: 16px;
       display: block;
       border: 2px solid black;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint non cumque at minima voluptates totam suscipit, esse vitae recusandae fugit, alias quibusdam odio sunt iure velit, perferendis voluptas ratione quo!</p>
</div>
```

sorry for stupid question
UPD: I'm sure this answer will be useful for the searchers that have similar troubles, plz do not delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because 0 is universal, 1 however depends on the unit, and since no unit is specified the browser doesn't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Because [`margin-*`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties) properties only accept lengths, percentages, and `auto`. Not integers.

> The properties defined in this section refer to the `<margin-width>`
>   value type, which may take one of the following values:
>
> - [`<length>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-length): Specifies a fixed width.
> - [`<percentage>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-percentage): The percentage is calculated with respect to
>     the width of the generated box's containing block.
> - `auto`

Then, `0` works because is a valid [length](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-length), but `1` isn't.

> The format of a length value (denoted by `<length>` in this
>   specification) is a [`<number>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-number) (with or without a decimal point)
>   immediately followed by a unit identifier (e.g., px, em, etc.). After
>   a zero length, the unit identifier is optional.

It would be valid if you added some unit like `1px`, `1cm`, `1em`, `1vh` or whatever.

Therefore, [your declaration is ignored](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#illegalvalues):

> User agents must ignore a declaration with an illegal value.

Answer (score 1):

0 by itself just means 0, but anything greater or lesser needs a unit. You can't say 1 and expect a length/size/etc.

0 means none and is valid. 1 by itself has no unit and CSS doesn't assume anything.

```
padding: 0px; /* px is redundant here because 0 means none */

padding: 1; /* error, what is 1? 1 cm? 1 em? */
```